# How can ask for something when I don't know what it is called?

Tags: support, questions

I posted a question asking for a certain syntax in PHP that was new for me at that time. I was  working on a project with legacy code; I work alone and I have nobody to ask.

This is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538675/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-this-syntax-temp-f

How can I ask for this kind of thing when I don't know how to describe it?

Comment: A relevant chat room can often help

Comment: I have zero understanding of PHP, so I may be way off base, but what I'm seeing your asking is "I have this block of code, how do I call it?".  If that is true, then the code itself isn't really an issue.  Ultimately, I don't see it being a good SO question.  @AndrewBarber is correct, you might find someone in chat who can lend some assistance as it will probably require more of walking you through the solution rather than a simple answer.

Comment: thank you for the response...it's good to know.